# how to delete special characters from mydsql data?

Tags: php

I am displaying content from database to xml file .In that some special character are displaying like..
                       world,rdquo , Caper,rdquo ,donrs ,  ldhe , ndash , Isnrs.

How can we remove this character .Please tell me the solutions.

Comment: I don't see any _special_ characters .. just mispelled words instead..

Comment: special character??? where

Comment: `&rdquo;` is the HTML code for a left curly double quote. I don't think you really want to remove these sorts of things.

Comment: i removed & and ; from that ..

Comment: not removing that has to converted to double quote,that's it @ ceejayoz

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific set of "special character" like you mentioned(only if), then define an array of those words/characters then replace it with blank value.

for example:

```
$splChar = array("world","rdquo","Caper","rdquo","donrs","ldhe","ndash","Isnrs");
$requiredContent = str_ireplace($splChar, "", $yourContent);
```

Note: Here str_ireplace is Case-insensitive

Comment: so many special chars are there..we have to convert dynamically

Answer (score 1):

The *"special characters"* **are correct** because their original presentation is not allowed inside an XML document.

Consider this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

When using the XML file, you turn the characters back either automatically by the XML library or manually by using `html_entity_decode()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

So when you want to change them INSIDE the XML document, this is against the rules for XML documents. You don't want to change them. You **don't need** to change them. If you don't want those characters, don't use XML. Use custom CSV then or whatever does not include escaping characters in their format.

If you want to change the characters AFTER processing the XML file:

```
echo html_entity_decode((string)$xml->node);
```

Comment: hi, actually I displayed some articles on my webpage from database.Same like that , i want to display that articles in xml also through php. But some special characters are came in to that.for example ..."let's" is there.this came like this letrs

Comment: Maybe UTF-8 / ISO encoding issue?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to replace special character then use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string="a$#rsdg123^";
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string);
```

output: `arsdg123`

Comment: remove special character from string.

Comment: the OP has mentioned the wordrs which need to be removed.not the #$